# Paraimpu HTTP POST REQUEST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to make a http POST request from my Jquery mobile application(hosted on Amazon S3) to "http://paraimpu.crs4.it/data/new" to insert data into my sensor on the Paraimpu site. This is the request I'm making:

```
        data = "Test";
        valueToSend = '{"token":"c9d1cee6-da40-4e97-afc8-209045786b04","content-type":"application/json","data":' + data + '}';
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://paraimpu.crs4.it/data/new",
            type: "POST",
            data: valueToSend,
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(){
            alert('Success');
        }
        });
```

I keep getting

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://paraimpu.crs4.it/data/new. Origin
>   "http://webappz.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I know this is because of the cross domain policy, but how can I get around this? The instructions on the paraimpu page are pretty vague and just says:

> Push new sensor data doing an HTTP POST to:
>
> http://paraimpu.crs4.it/data/new
>
> with content like: {"token":"c9d1cee6-da40-4e97-afc8-209045786b04",
>   "content-type":"text/plain", "data":RAW DATA}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = "Test";
valueToSend = '{"token":"c9d1cee6-da40-4e97-afc8-209045786b04","content-type":"application/json","data":' + data + '}';
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://paraimpu.crs4.it/data/new",
        type: "POST",
        data: valueToSend,
        dataType: "jsonp",    //set datatype to jsonp
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: false,
        contentType:"application/json",
        success: function(){
            alert('Success');
        }
    });​
```

These are the parts that you were missing:

`dataType: "jsonp"`: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. "jsonp", loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.

`jsonp: false`: Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the query string in the url. So {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in 'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting. For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

More on this here: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work. Using JSONP automatically turns the request into a GET and I get '400 Bad Request' as a response